Hibernate StaleObjectStateException After Upgrading to 6.6.3: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect
Note: Before marking this a duplicate, please understand that I have gone through all the existing answers and issues but could not resolve the same.
I have two PostgreSQL tables: one for Product and another for gallery images with SEO details. Here are the schemas:
create table if not exists test_product
(
    id      bigserial   not null,
    version bigserial   not null,
    name    text        not null,
    sku     varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists test_product_image_gallery_seo
(
    id         bigserial not null,
    version    bigserial not null,
    product_id bigint    not null,
    image      text      not null,
    alt_text   text      not null,
    primary key (id),
    constraint fk_product_id foreign key (product_id) references test_product (id),
    constraint test_unique_seo unique (product_id, image)
);

In my Spring Boot application, I have two Hibernate ORM entities representing these tables. Below are their definitions:
TestProduct

@Entity(name = "test_product")
@Table(name = "test_product")
public class TestProduct extends BehemothORM {

    @Column(
        name = ProductContract.NAME,
        nullable = false,
        unique = true,
        columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String name;

    @Column(
        name = ProductContract.SKU,
        nullable = false,
        unique = true,
        columnDefinition = "VARCHAR"
    )
    private String sku;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "product",
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        targetEntity = TestProductImageGallerySEO.class,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<TestProductImageGallerySEO> imageGallerySEOList;
}

TestProductGalleryImageSEO
@Entity(name = "test_product_gallery_image_seo")
@Table(
    name = "test_product_gallery_image_seo",
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(
            name = "test_unique_seo",
            columnNames = {
                ProductImageGallerySEOContract.PRODUCT_ID,
                ProductImageGallerySEOContract.IMAGE
            }
        )
    }
)
public class TestProductImageGallerySEO extends BehemothORM {

    @Column(
        name = "image", 
        columnDefinition = "TEXT", 
        nullable = false
    )
    private String image;

    @Column(
        name = "alt_text", 
        columnDefinition = "TEXT", 
        nullable = false
    )
    private String altText;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(
        targetEntity = TestProduct.class,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinColumn(
        name = ProductImageGallerySEOContract.PRODUCT_ID,
        columnDefinition = "BIGSERIAL",
        nullable = false,
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
            name = "fk_product_id"
        )
    )
    @GsonExclude
    private TestProduct product;
    
    @Transient
    private boolean deleted = false;
}

Here's the logic where I add or update gallery images for a product:
 @Transactional()
    public int modifyGalleryImages(@NotNull TestProductImageGallerySEOPayload seoPayload) {

        // gets the current product as entity from database
        TestProduct product = this.testProductDAOController.retrieveEntity(seoPayload.getProductId());

        for (TestProductImageGallerySEO imageGallerySEO : seoPayload.getGallerySEOList()) 
        {
            imageGallerySEO.setProduct(product);
            this.addNewEntity(imageGallerySEO);
        }

        return ActionCode.UPDATE_SUCCESS;
    }

This code was working previously. However, after upgrading Hibernate versions this exact code is failing without any changes made.
After upgrading Hibernate from version 6.3.1 to 6.6.3, I'm getting the following error:
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.bloomscorp.loom.seo.orm.TestProductImageGallerySEO#0]

This error occurs when trying to save a new TestProductImageGallerySEO entity using addNewEntity. Here is the seoPayload
{
    "productId": 37503,
    "gallerySEOList": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "version": 0,
            "image": "uvw.jpg",
            "altText": "",
            "deleted": false
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "version": 0,
            "image": "https://abc.jpg",
            "altText": "",
            "deleted": false
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "version": 0,
            "image": "https://xyz.jpg",
            "altText": "",
            "deleted": false
        }
    ]
}

Additional Context:
if anybody wants to know what BehemothORM and addNewEntity does, these are basically our own set of libraries that we use to speed up the development process. Here is the defination of these two
BehemothORM
BehemothORM is a base class with common fields like id and version
addNewEntity
addNewEntity is a wrapper around JpaRepository.save()
Questions:

Why does this error occur now after upgrading Hibernate?
How can I fix this error while retaining the current logic?

Thanks in advance!
Edit
As requested by @M.Deinum here is the complete stacktrace
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.bloomscorp.loom.seo.orm.TestProductImageGallerySEO#0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at com.bloomscorp.nverse.NVerseRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(NVerseRequestFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at com.bloomscorp.nverse.NVerseExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(NVerseExceptionHandlerFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at com.bloomscorp.nverse.NVerseHttpRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(NVerseHttpRequestFilter.java:20)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:219)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.bloomscorp.loom.seo.orm.TestProductImageGallerySEO#0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:304)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:232)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:243)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy265.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.bloomscorp.behemoth.dao.controller.AbstractAddEntityDAOController.addNewEntity(AbstractAddEntityDAOController.java:22)
    at com.bloomscorp.loom.seo.dao.controller.TestProductImageGallerySEODAOController.modifyGalleryImages(TestProductImageGallerySEODAOController.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at com.bloomscorp.loom.seo.dao.controller.TestProductImageGallerySEODAOController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.modifyGalleryImages(<generated>)
    at com.bloomscorp.loom.seo.controller.ProductImageGallerySEOController.lambda$modifyGalleryImages$1(ProductImageGallerySEOController.java:126)
    at com.bloomscorp.behemoth.controller.AbstractPostEntityController.post(AbstractPostEntityController.java:95)
    at com.bloomscorp.behemoth.controller.AbstractPostEntityController.postEntityEnhancedResponse(AbstractPostEntityController.java:280)
    at com.bloomscorp.behemoth.controller.AbstractPostEntityController.postEntity(AbstractPostEntityController.java:140)
    at com.bloomscorp.behemoth.controller.AbstractPostEntityController.postEntity(AbstractPostEntityController.java:167)
    at com.bloomscorp.loom.seo.controller.ProductImageGallerySEOController.modifyGalleryImages(ProductImageGallerySEOController.java:117)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at com.bloomscorp.nverse.validator.NVerseValidationAspect.validateByDomainValidator(NVerseValidationAspect.java:67)
    at com.bloomscorp.nverse.validator.NVerseValidationAspect.validateDomainContext(NVerseValidationAspect.java:123)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:637)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:71)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at com.bloomscorp.loom.seo.controller.ProductImageGallerySEOController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.modifyGalleryImages(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    ... 61 more

Also below is the controller code which invokes the modifyGalleryImages function,
    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(
        value = "modify/test/gallery-images",
        consumes = Constant.REQUEST_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON,
        produces = Constant.RESPONSE_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON
    )
    public RainTreeResponse modifyGalleryImages(
        NVerseHttpRequestWrapper request,
        @RequestBody TestProductImageGallerySEOPayload gallerySEOPayload
    ) {
        return this.postEntity(
            request,
            "modifyGalleryImages",
            CODE_SUCU,
            UNAUTH_GALLERY_IMAGE_REQUEST,
            NEW_GALLERY_IMAGE_CREATED,
            this.testValidator,
            new TestProductImageGallerySEOPayloadSanitizer(),
            gallerySEOPayload,
            () -> this.testSEODAOController.modifyGalleryImages(
                this.getAuthorityResolver().resolveUserInformationFromAuthorizationToken(
                    request.getHeader(Constant.REQUEST_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION)
                ),
                gallerySEOPayload
            )
        );
    }

Please ignore the library level codes as those are already tested. The controller is invoking the modifyGalleryImages method once a request hits the controller.

You are using Spring BOot why are you manually updating hibernate, as that can lead to you including an unsupported version. For your question please add the full stacktrcae you get and explain how the modifyGalleryImages is called.

In my case it was not the upgrade to 6.6.3-final, but the upgrade to Spring Boot 3.4.0 / Springdoc 2.7. After going back to spring boot 3.3.5 and springdoc 2.6 my tests were green again.

@M.Deinum are you suggesting we should not mention the hibernate version in the pom.xml file?

@M.Deinum I have updated the question with the stacktrace and controller code.

@Thirdman Well I have updated the spring boot as well.

If you are using Spring Boot there should ideally be no mention of any framework that is already pulled in by the Spring Boot starters (unless there is a very good reason to do so). If you try to outsmart the dependency management you might end up with incompatible versions of frameworks in use.

@M.Deinum I am having an issue where hibernate search is erroring out due to the upgrade. It's version is not managed directly by spring-boot-starter-parent afaik. I am using hibernate-search-mapper-orm and hibernate-search-backend-lucene, both at 7.2.2.Final (errors out without mentioning the version). How would you suggest I approach this versioning problem?

Don't hijack a question open a new one instead.

@M.Deinum I am facing the exact same error that OP is facing and I followed your advice to remove explicit dependencies. While that works, the issue has come down to the hibernate search dependency that I have mentioned. Do you think it would be better if I raised a new question but with almost the same issue?
